# How to inplace pop/append with 2D Numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I have an image frame of dimensions `640x512` stored as a Numpy array of all white pixels. I want to constantly remove/pop(0) the left most column and append it with a black column in each iteration. Essentially, I'm trying to shift the image from right to left to eventually replace the entire image with black pixels, one column at a time. I've attempted to use `np.concatenate()` but I keep getting these two errors.

> ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions
>
> ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (512,1) into shape (640)

If possible, I would like to do this inplace. Here's an illustration.

Initial blank frame of size `640x512`

[image]

Each iteration adds a new black column (1 pixel) to the frame, with the end result having a completely black image

[image]

This pop/push action is similar to a queue but instead I want to do this directly on the 2D Numpy arrays. I don't want to use any other data structure since I'm putting these images directly into OpenCV so I would like to keep it as a Numpy array. How can I shift the 2D numpy array one pixel at a time?

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

black_column = np.zeros([512,1], dtype=np.uint8)
blank_pixels = np.zeros([512, 640], dtype=np.uint8)
blank_pixels[:] = 255

while True:
    # Pop
    blank_pixels[:-1] = blank_pixels[1:]
    # Push
    blank_pixels[-1] = black_column

    #blank_pixels[:] = np.concatenate(blank_pixels[1:], black_column)

    cv2.imshow('blank_pixels', blank_pixels)
    cv2.waitKey(1)
```

Comment: Why not just keep track of the iteration and assign black pixels to the `nth` column?  `concatenate` is going to be much slower than assignment

Comment: I'm looking for the syntax to do this since I need to know the process of how to append/pop with 2D Numpy arrays. The real application is for a "waterfall" moving frame effect that takes in a image from a scientific camera. I'm able to isolate the frame by frame column camera data and need to append this to the frame I'm displaying on a GUI. The black pixels in each iteration essentially simulates a new frame of column camera data

Comment: Assigning over the `nth` column each iteration accomplishes the exact same thing, just more efficiently.

Comment: Will that method also give a sliding/shifting effect from right to left? I'm not sure how to implement that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assignment will be a much more efficient option than concatenation here.

---

```
blank = np.full((640, 512), 255, dtype=np.uint8)

for i in range(blank.shape[1]-1, -1, -1):
    blank[:, i] = 0
    cv2.imshow('img', blank)
    cv2.waitKey(1)
```

---

Produces this:

[image]

---

For non-white images, you can `roll` with this:

```
blank = np.random.randint(1, 256, (640, 512), dtype=np.uint8)

for i in range(blank.shape[1]-1, -1, -1):
    blank = np.roll(blank, -1, axis=1)
    blank[:, -1] = 0
    cv2.imshow('img', blank)
    cv2.waitKey(1)
```

---

This produces:

[image]

Comment: This only works because the initial image is all-white. With a different initial image, this would produce an effect of sliding a black curtain over the image, while the effect the question asks for would look like sliding the initial image out of view. Those effects just happen to be equivalent for an all-white initial image.

Comment: Awesome, exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 2):

I can't see the pictures you provided. Are you talking about the effect like this?

```
import cv2
import numpy as np


blank_pixels = np.ones([512, 640], dtype=np.uint8)*255

for i in range(640):
    # Pop
    blank_pixels[:, :-1] = blank_pixels[:, 1:]
    # Push
    blank_pixels[:, -1] = 0
    cv2.imshow('blank_pixels', blank_pixels)
    cv2.waitKey(1)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 2):

`blank_pixels[:,:1] = black_column`